# How can I display ajax results in a view in CakePHP without including the default template in the ajax response?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm doing some experimenting with AJAX in CakePHP and it seems to work except that the view that gets returned includes the default template.  How can I get rid of that (or even just specify a different empty template for a view)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    //do stuff
    $this->layout= 'ajax';
}
```

Ajax is an included blank layout to prevent extra markup being added, exactly what you want.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/96/Layouts

Comment: That is exactly it!  Thanks!  That layout still includes debug info but now that I look it's just the SQL and not the controller dump which is exactly what I would need . . very cool.

Answer (score 5):

Try using RequestHandler component.  This will be handled automatically for you.  Then, you can do something like this in your AppController::beforeFilter()

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    Configure::write('debug',0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to turn off debug output otherwise cake will squirt out all the debug info you usually see at the bottom of the page:

```
function ajaxFunction() {
    //do stuff
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->layout= 'ajax';
}
```